# Binding checkbox issue in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm, binding

I am facing a problem in getting the value from VM for checkbox IsChecked binding value. (I'm using MVVM Light).

**My issue**: When checkbox IsChecked is changed, it is not firing back to my VM property that I bind to.

Below is the code.

I have a class with boolean values (in a class file).

```
public class Rights
{
    public bool bSales { get; set; }
    public bool bProduct { get; set; }
    public bool bZone { get; set; }
    public bool bPercentage { get; set; }
    public bool bUser { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the property that my checkboxes will bind to (in VM).

```
private Rights user_Rights;
public Rights User_Rights
{
    get { return user_Rights; }
    set { Set(ref user_Rights, value); }
}
```

And below is the property for my 'Select All' check box (in VM).

```
private bool? rights_All;
public bool? Rights_All
{
    get { return rights_All; }
    set
    {
        Set(ref rights_All, value);

        if (value == true)
        {
            User_Rights = new Rights() { bSales = true, bProduct = true, bPercentage = true, bZone = true, bUser = true };
        }
        else if(value == false)
        {
            User_Rights = new Rights() { bSales = false, bProduct = false, bPercentage = false, bZone = false, bUser = false };
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, below is my XAML for the binding.

```
<CheckBox Content="Sales PIC" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bSales,Mode=TwoWay}" />
<CheckBox Content="Product" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bProduct,Mode=TwoWay}" />
<CheckBox Content="Zone" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bZone,Mode=TwoWay}" />
<CheckBox Content="Percentage" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bPercentage}" />
<CheckBox Content="User" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bUser}" />
<CheckBox Content="Select All" IsChecked="{Binding Rights_All}" />
```

Here is what I am doing in picture.
[image]

Any suggestion on where did I do wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't your model (`Rights`) also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: I’m guessing that “not firing back to a vm property” is your way of saying that it’s not setting the properties of the Rights object. Is that what you’re trying to say? How are you checking that?

Comment: Tested. Works as expected. Either your private meaning of "trigger back to VM" and "firing back to VM" is so exotic as to be unguessable with any confidence from the evidence in your question (are you hoping that default setters on `Rights` properties will somehow call the setter of `User_Rights` on a completely different class?), or you're looking at the wrong instance of `Rights`. If it's option #1, clarify. If it's option #2, just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `Rights`. If it's #3, the question should be closed.

Comment: Ideally, you should not reassign value of `User_Rights` again and again. Instead have a method inside `Rights` like `SelectAll` and `UnselectAll` and call from `Rights_All`.

Comment: `User_Rights = new Rights() { bSales = (bool)value, ...etc.`, without the two if branches, would be nicer code IMO. @NikhilAgrawal If `User_Rights` (ideally, the naming conventions wouldn't be an odd mix of SQL and MFC) has a setter, there shouldn't be any harm in calling it -- and that part is coded correctly and works fine. I wouldn't object about that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, thanks for your explanation and sorry for the confusion questions that I used. I mean the checkbox check status does not fire back to my User_Rights property although I bind to it. After you saying it is working, I put a lot of break point and I found that it did fire back to my Model class (where my Rights class located). And like you and zaitsman mentioned, I tried to implements INotifyPropertyChanged and now it is working View will fire back to my Model. And when I change the value from VM, it will also reflect on View.

Comment: Perdon me for another question (am not sure related to this or should open a new thread). Since it is fire from my Model to View. What is the logic if I want to change "Rights_All" value ? Because when I deselect one of the checkbox (if fires back to Model), the "Select all" should go into null (not in true or false state). I can do it from VM but User_Rights property does not fire so I am out of cluse on where should I put this code to change it in my VM.

Comment: @scsfdev View will never "fire back to [your] model". Setting a property is not raising an event. Please do not make up your own terminology, because then people have to guess what you mean. When people are trying to help you, it is disrespectful to make them guess what you are talking about. Just say what the code is actually doing. If it is (or isn't) setting a property, say it is (or isn't) setting a property.

Comment: As I mention, I am using MVVM light. Thanks for your explanation and I am not sure why you said I am making people confuse. I mentioned did not "fire" (call back) to my biding in my viewmodel. I am not sure how you want to define these if I should not use "fire back". And when I put the break point in my Model class where INotifyProperty is implemented (after you guys suggestion), it did call back to it when I click on the view, that's why I mention it fire back to Model (I also put break point in my VM, but it didn't go there).

Comment: Because there are a lot of people will ask "so, what is your issue, what is your problem" then I need to state my issue "not firing back to my VM". If this makes you confuse, I apologize. But kindly take note I did not mean to confuse people who are helping to people like me who needs support.

Comment: @scsfdev “Fire” doesn’t mean that. I told you that several times. You should apologize for being deliberately difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my solution (after getting suggestion from @Ed Plunkett and @zaitsman)
I implemented INotifyProperty (by using MVVM Light way) to one of the classes in my Model.

For my Model Class.

```
public class Rights: ViewModelBase
{
    public Rights()
    {
        _bSalesPIC = false;
        _bZone = false;
        ... (etc)
        _bAll = false;
    }

    private bool _bSalesPIC;
    public bool bSalesPIC
    {
        get { return _bSalesPIC; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _bSalesPIC, value);
            TriggerAll();
        }
    }

    private bool _bZone;
    public bool bZone
    {
        get { return _bZone; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _bZone, value);
            TriggerAll();
        }
    }

    private bool? _bAll;
    public bool? bAll
    {
        get { return _bAll; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _bAll , value);

            if (value == true)
            {
                _bSalesPIC = true;
                _bZone = true;
                RaisePropertyChanged("bSalesPIC");
                RaisePropertyChanged("bZone");
            }
            else if (value == false)
            {
                _bSalesPIC = false;
                _bZone = false;

                RaisePropertyChanged("bSalesPIC");
                RaisePropertyChanged("bZone");
            }
        }
    }

    private void TriggerAll()
    {
        if (_bSalesPIC && _bZone && etc)
            bAll = true;
        else if (!_bSalesPIC && !_bZone && etc)
            bAll = false;
        else
            bAll = null;
    }
```

For my VM.

```
    private Rights user_Rights;
    public Rights User_Rights
    {
        get { return user_Rights; }
        set { Set(ref user_Rights, value); }
    }
```

And for my View (XAML).

```
    <CheckBox Content="Sales PIC" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bSalesPIC}" />
    <CheckBox Content="Sales Input" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bSalesInput}" />
    <CheckBox Content="Product" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bProduct}" />
    <CheckBox Content="Zone" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bZone}" />
    <CheckBox Content="Percentage" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bPercentage}" />
    <CheckBox Content="User" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bUser}" />
    <CheckBox Content="Select All" IsChecked="{Binding User_Rights.bAll}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your viewmodel base class is called, so I just used my own. I don't know how your `Set()` method works; this may take a little adaptation on your part. That'll have to be your job; it's your turn. I wrote this because explaining the logic to you would take longer than writing the code. You should read this code and understand it, rather than simply pasting it into your project.

Note that I've written this using conventional C# naming conventions. The boolean properties no longer have the `b` prefix. This means you have to remove that prefix from the paths in the bindings in your XAML.

Note also that I renamed `Rights_All` to `All`, *and moved it to a different viewmodel*. It is now a member of the `Rights` viewmodel. This also will require a change to your bindings.

You should consider using a `Flags` enum for your rights. This would simplify the code a bit, and make it easier to add additional rights in the future.

```
public class Rights : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _sales;
    public bool Sales {
        get { return _sales; }
        set { SetRightFlag(ref _sales, value); }
    }

    private bool _product;
    public bool Product
    {
        get { return _product; }
        set { SetRightFlag(ref _product, value); }
    }

    private bool _zone;
    public bool Zone
    {
        get { return _zone; }
        set { SetRightFlag(ref _zone, value); }
    }

    private bool _percentage;
    public bool Percentage
    {
        get { return _percentage; }
        set { SetRightFlag(ref _percentage, value); }
    }

    private bool _user;
    public bool User
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set { SetRightFlag(ref _user, value); }
    }

    //  This logic needs to happen in five different setters, so I put it in a 
    //  method. 
    private bool SetRightFlag(ref bool field, bool value, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        if (field != value)
        {
            Set(ref field, value, propName);
            UpdateAll();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //  I made this its own method as well, for cleanliness and clarity, even though 
    //  it's only called once. 
    protected void UpdateAll()
    {
        //  Don't call the All setter from here, because it has side effects.
        if (User && Percentage && Zone && Product && Sales)
        {
            _all = true;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(All));
        }
        else if (!User && !Percentage && !Zone && !Product && !Sales)
        {
            _all = false;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(All));
        }
        else if (All.HasValue)
        {
            _all = null;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(All));
        }
    }

    private bool? _all = null;
    public bool? All
    {
        get { return _all; }
        set {
            if (_all != value)
            {
                Set(ref _all, value);
                if (_all.HasValue)
                {
                    User = Percentage = Zone = Product = Sales = (bool)_all;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code and suggestion about 'naming' and 'enum'. Since I didn't use enum in such way before, will give it a study.